# Grab filtered arrays parents as well

Tags: javascript

I was trying to compare two arrays for different values and filter them out accordingly. I managed to get the filter on the children values how I wanted. However, I was wondering if it's possible that I can also grab the filtered results of the parented Array not just there children?

Here is my code:

```js
let arrayOne = {
  smallBall: [
    'randomball',
    'anotherrandomball',
    'bigball',
    'smallball'
  ],
  mediumBall: [
    'mediumballsize',
    'mediumsmallsizeball',
    'randommediumball',
    'anothermediumball'
  ]
}

let arrayTwo = {
  smallBall: [
    'randomball',
    'anotherrandomball',
    'bigballdifferent',
    'smallballdifferent'
  ],
  mediumBall: [
    'mediumballsize',
    'mediumsmallsizeball',
    'randommediumballdifferent',
    'anothermediumballdifferent'
  ]
}

// Loop through first Array
let firstnewArray = [];
for (var first in arrayOne) {
  for (i = 0; i < arrayOne[first].length; i++) {
    // Push the contents into a new array
    firstnewArray.push(arrayOne[first][i]);
  }
}

let secondnewArray = [];
for (var second in arrayTwo) {
  for (i = 0; i < arrayTwo[second].length; i++) {
    // Push the contents into a new array
    secondnewArray.push(arrayTwo[second][i]);
  }
}

let abDifference = firstnewArray.filter(x => secondnewArray.indexOf(x) == -1);
let baDifference = secondnewArray.filter(x => firstnewArray.indexOf(x) == -1);

// Original Arrays

console.log(firstnewArray);
console.log(secondnewArray);


// Filtered Results from new array that was pushed

console.log(abDifference);
console.log(baDifference);
```

Comment: What do you mean "filter"?

Comment: Please provide the expected output for the input arrays you have given.

Comment: The difference between the two values of the two arrays. I was wondering if I can also grab the parents in there initial array as well not just there values. In the console.log, it just gives me there difference in values.

Comment: Again, please provide the *expected output* for the input arrays you have given. There is no parent array in your question, and it is not clear what the difference would entail.

Comment: I provided the console.log of the original arrays of what I'm referring to. I guess I have the context wrong by when I said "Parent" I'm trying to grab the filtered arrays objects as well. So for example, Small Ball, Medium ball.

Comment: Maybe `Object.keys()` https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys is what you are looking for, in order to diff the keys of the objects...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the result to look the same as the original objects (not arrays), but with nested items removed from them when they appear in both, then you can use this function:

```js
function diff(a, b) {
    const c = {};
    for (const [key, arr] of Object.entries(a)) {
        const filtered = arr.filter( s => !(b[key] && b[key].includes(s)) );
        if (filtered.length) c[key] = filtered;
    }
    return c;
}

// Sample input
let arrayOne = {smallBall: ['randomball','anotherrandomball','bigball','smallball'],mediumBall:['mediumballsize','mediumsmallsizeball','randommediumball','anothermediumball']};
let arrayTwo = {smallBall: ['randomball','anotherrandomball','bigballdifferent','smallballdifferent'],mediumBall: ['mediumballsize','mediumsmallsizeball','randommediumballdifferent','anothermediumballdifferent']};

// Results
console.log(diff(arrayOne, arrayTwo));
console.log(diff(arrayTwo, arrayOne));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

@Thomas Junk's answer is exactly what you need. Just modify the two arrays with the Object keys. Just add this code before the filter logic.

```
Object.keys(arrayOne).forEach(item => firstnewArray.push(item));
Object.keys(arrayTwo).forEach(item => secondnewArray.push(item));
```